# Correct way to update react component from secondary source

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm kind of new with React Hooks and I've encountered a problem when making a component. My App has a simple form with a few fields and a "Calculate" button which fetches info from an API and displays the results on a table. The app uses two currencies, they can be switched with a pair of buttons. What I want is to update the table(re fetch the data) when currency is changed, but only is there was already something calculated via the main "Calculate" button before changing the currency. My component is something along the lines of:

```
const ProductionCosts = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({}); 
  const [useXCurrency, setUseXCurrency] = useState(true);


  const calcCosts = useCallback(async () => {

    fetchCalcData(args);
  }, [args]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(data).length > 0) //check data isn't empty, hence it was already calculated
      fetchCalcData();
  }, [useXCurrency]);



  return (
   ......

  );
};
```

Doing something similar to the above works, but the linter will say that data needs to be in the dependency list of the useEffect, but adding it will result on a loop given that fetchCalcData modifies data and triggers the effect, I DO know that the linter suggestions aren't absolute, but at the same time I know that there must be a better way. So besides adding Boolean flags or something like that, there is a better approach to this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you want to use a refenence with the initial value and update it on success, on next `useEffect` the condition will be falsy:

```
const ProductionCosts = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const dataRef = useRef(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(dataRef.current).length > 0) {
      const data = // fetch your data
      dataRef.current = data;
    }
  }, [useXCurrency]);

  return <></>;
};
```